# Custom HttpClient for RemoteConverter of Documents4j

Tags: java, jersey, httpclient, documents4j

I am using a `RemoteConverter` from a jBoss web application to a standalone server built as the default `server-standalone` included into documents4j project.

Inside jboss I've got an old version of required libraries `httpclient-4.0.1.jar` and related `httpcore-4.0.1.jar` so I'm facing with a lot of `ClassDefNotFoundException` caused by the different version of the jar loaded by JVM.

There is a specific problem with `HttpClientConnectionManager` object that is not available yet in version

To avoid this problem I'd like to bluild a custom http client for the `standalone-server`, because, due to the previous problems, it's not possible for me to use `Jersey`.

Has someone build a different client for that `standalone-server`? What are the specs to build a custom `RemoteClient`?

**UPDATE 1**

After a little bit of analysis with the help of a sniffing tool, I figured out the composition of the message, so I've just ended a custom `HttpClient` for that server as following:

```
    File wordFile = new File("C:/temp/test.docx");
    InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(wordFile);

    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9998");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/vnd.com.documents4j.any-msword");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/pdf");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Converter-Job-Priority", "1000");


    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    os.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(targetStream));
    os.flush();

    if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
            + conn.getResponseCode());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));
    FileWriter ostream = new FileWriter("C:/temp/test.pdf");
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(ostream);
    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
        out.write(output+"\n");
    }
    br.close();
    out.close();
    os.close();
    conn.disconnect();
```

Now I've got another problem, if I try to open just created test.pdf file it is all white but with the right number of pages. If I open the file with a text editor and analyze the beginning and the end of file I found the following chars:

```
%PDF-1.5
%µµµµ
1 0 obj  
[...]
startxref
1484122
%%EOF
```

It seems to be a good PDF file.

There is something else to do with that file received from REST Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before answering your question: I would recommend you to rather [**shade**](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) the dependency then to reimplement it.

I can imagine that you are facing an encoding issue when implementing your own service. A `BufferedReader` translates the incoming data to character data. Do not read data by character line but treat it as binary. Instead of *Writer* classes use the *Stream* classes. This is why the meta data is treated correctly as it is represented by characters but the actual data is illegal as it is binary information:

```
InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:/temp/test.pdf");
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
```