# DOCX to PDF conversion java using document4j remotely

Tags: java, maven, pdf, documents4j

I am currently trying to convert an advanced word document (.DOCX) to PDF using java.

For the generation of word documents I am using apache poi@3.15. They have a PDF converter build in, although it kind of ruins the document format.

I eventually ended up using a cloud based API (paid), which felt like a bummer. Today though, I found the document4j project and it got me very excited.

I have purchased a VPS which runs windows for the sole purpose of converting .docx files to .pdf files and it is reachable. The document4j/local-demo is working fine as well and is capable of converting my .docx files to .pdf very nicely.

There seems to be very limited documentation online though, except for the Javadocs, which don't help me out anymore than the intellisense in my editor does.

Can anybody help me out with this?

### Stacktrace

```
2018-11-28 00:37:21.577  INFO 701 --- [o-8081-exec-477] com.documents4j.job.RemoteConverter      : The documents4j remote converter has started successfully (URI: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1337)
Exception in thread "pool-3-thread-1" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.PropertiesHelper.getValue(Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.getSslContext(ApacheConnector.java:324)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.<init>(ApacheConnector.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnectorProvider.getConnector(ApacheConnectorProvider.java:110)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.initRuntime(ClientConfig.java:425)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.access$000(ClientConfig.java:90)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State$3.get(ClientConfig.java:122)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State$3.get(ClientConfig.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValueImpl.get(Values.java:340)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.getRuntime(ClientConfig.java:733)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.getConfiguration(ClientRequest.java:286)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.validateHttpMethodAndEntity(JerseyInvocation.java:135)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:105)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:101)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.<init>(JerseyInvocation.java:92)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$AsyncInvoker.method(JerseyInvocation.java:642)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$AsyncInvoker.post(JerseyInvocation.java:520)
        at com.documents4j.job.RemoteFutureWrappingPriorityFuture.startConversion(RemoteFutureWrappingPriorityFuture.java:61)
        at com.documents4j.job.RemoteFutureWrappingPriorityFuture.startConversion(RemoteFutureWrappingPriorityFuture.java:15)
        at com.documents4j.job.AbstractFutureWrappingPriorityFuture.run(AbstractFutureWrappingPriorityFuture.java:70)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

### pom.xml

```
....

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.documents4j/documents4j-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>documents4j-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

....
```

### Relevant code:

```
IConverter converter = RemoteConverter.builder()
                    .baseFolder(null)
                    .workerPool(20, 25, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .requestTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .baseUri("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1337")
                    .build();

                File pdfFile = File.createTempFile(fileName, ".pdf");
                pdfFile.deleteOnExit();

                converter.convert(data).as(DocumentType.DOCX).to(pdfFile).as(DocumentType.PDF).execute();
```

Edit: using `java -jar ./documents4j-client-standalone-1.0.3-shaded.jar http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1337` works, though unfortunately not in the java code itself.

Answer (score 2):

This is an obvious dependency version conflict. Check what version of Glassfish you are using and what version of Glassfish documents4j depends on. Run *mvn dependency:tree* to help you figure this out.

Comment: Well.. its less obvious to me, since I am not using glassfish in my own project, my project is based on Spring MVC/boot.

I have tried the mvn enforcer:enforce plugin, and that tells me that the documents4j-client is using jersey-client@2.25.1, which depends on javax.ws.rs-api@2.0.1, while also depending on jersey-apache-connector@2.6, which depends on javax.ws.rs-api@2.0. I am not getting any more relevant errors/warnings than this I am afraid.

Comment: Could it be that I am missing dependencies besides documents4j-client ? I only need to use the RemoteConverter

Answer (score 0):

My problem was similar to this issue and was solved by creating a custom HTTP request:

[Custom HttpClient for RemoteConverter of Documents4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37028962/custom-httpclient-for-remoteconverter-of-documents4j)