# I need to convert my docx extension file into pdf using document4j remote converter by using java

Tags: java

I am getting the following errror

> Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException:
>   org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to
>   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1337 [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/123.176.40.69] failed: connect
>   timed out     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:498)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector$1.run(ApacheConnector.java:508)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:293)
>     at
>   jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit(AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:49)
>     at
>   jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit(AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:45)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:504)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$1.run(ClientRuntime.java:150)
>     at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)  at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:319)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime$2.run(ClientRuntime.java:182)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

---

```
File inputWord = new File("E:\\PrivateAndConfidential.docx");
            IConverter converter = RemoteConverter.builder()
                    .baseFolder(null)
                    .workerPool(20, 25, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .requestTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                   .baseUri("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1337")
                    .build();
                File pdfFile = File.createTempFile("E:\\PrivateAndConfidential", ".pdf");
                pdfFile.deleteOnExit();

                converter.convert(inputWord).as(DocumentType.DOCX).to(pdfFile).as(DocumentType.PDF).execute();
```

I need to convert that document into pdf which includes in the document all the type of shapes and tables every thing..

Comment: `org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1337` - you'r base URI `baseUri("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1337")` is wrong :)

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53510016/docx-to-pdf-conversion-java-using-document4j-remotely)